# i am getting a 3011 error even though its able to find the object

Tags: ms-access, vba

Can someone help me with this? It seems like access is able to pick up the object. However, it somehow states that it can't find it. What is wrong? Thank you

```
Private Sub bImportFiles_Click()
On Error GoTo bImportFiles_Click_Err

Dim objFS As Object, objFolder As Object
Dim objFiles As Object, objF1 As Object
Dim strFolderPath As String

strFolderPath = "C:\Documents\HS\"
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
Set objFiles = objFolder.files

For Each objF1 In objFiles
If Right(objF1.Name, 3) = "txt" Then
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "HS Import Specification", "tblHS", strFolderPath &    objF1.Name, True
End If
Next

Set objF1 = Nothing
Set objFiles = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFS = Nothing

bImportFiles_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

bImportFiles_Click_Err:
MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Resume bImportFiles_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line triggers the error?  Also there should be more text in that error message --- it usually identifies which object it's complaining about.  Please show us the full error message.

Comment: I think it is somewhere near this line: DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "HS Import Specification", "tblHS", strFolderPath &    objF1.Name, True .    Here is the full message: 3011 The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'HS_2011.01.01 text.txt'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly

Answer (score 1):

Access does not like dots(.) in the file name. Try replace your (.) with (_) like
'HS_2011_01_01 text.txt'